# Default maximum heap size for JavaExec Gradle task

Tags: gradle

When defining an own JavaExec type of task, what is the default maximum heap size is I do not explicitly set it?

Gradle documentation is just quiet about that.

Comment: Can you get it and check? if there is a setter there should be a getter as well? ;)

Comment: hmm just checked the documentation, it says _Returns null if the default maximum heap size should be used._ and you right doesn't say what it is anywhere.

Comment: Maybe @Vampire would know the answer to this.

Comment: The answer is `512MB` and comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678712/where-does-the-maximum-heap-size-get-set-when-running-a-unit-test-with-gradle).

Answer (score 0):

I think Gradle looks first on the arguments passed on the command line then checks another jvmArgs set elsewhere, like `gradle.properties` etc.

If can't find anything its just going to use defaults, still depending what Java has been used I think.

I believe you could look at the Gradle source and you will find DefaultJavaForkOptions and JvmOptions and DaemonForkOptions classes - if not specified in fork.options, and not on the gradlew command line then it will use whatever java has.

But this is jsut some of the investigation, I might be wrong.

Comment: Sad is that there is no answer in the documentation for such a basic question :( But thanks anyway, will have to play a Sherlock role for a while.