# Where does the maximum heap size get set when running a unit test with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I had a failing OOM unit test and wondered why I needed to manually allow for bigger `maxHeapSize` like so:

```
test {
  maxHeapSize = '4G'
}
```

I assumed the max heap is not capped and couldn't find anything in gradle api sources to prove me wrong. However, running gradle with `--info` clearly reveals otherwise:

```
Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 427'. Working directory: [project-dir] Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dorg.gradle.native=false -javaagent:build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.6.jar_a26f6511a7813217be4cd6439d66563b/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/test.exec,append=true,inclnolocationclasses=false,dumponexit=true,output=file,jmx=false -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -cp /Users/[user]/.gradle/caches/6.4/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 427'
```

My question is where does the `-Xmx512m` above come from?

Next to that, is there a way to allow for unlimited max heap and would that be a totally unreasonable thing to do?

*possible duplicate of [Default maximum heap size for JavaExec Gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737680/default-maximum-heap-size-for-javaexec-gradle-task)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `512m` default is set in [`DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/124712713a77a6813e112ae1b68f248deca6a816/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/process/internal/worker/DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder.java#L230). `512m` is a tradeoff, working for small to medium sized projects and given that multiple workers can be running simultaneously. According to the [commit message](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/9a92c84e58af24f4ce8300cc875597aadb4f41f1):

> **Limit memory for worker processes by default**
>
> Our workers for compilation, testing etc. had no default
> memory settings until now, which mean that we would use
> the default given by the JVM, which is 1/4th of system memory
> in most cases. This is way too much when running with a high
> number of workers. Limiting this to 256m should be enough for
> small to medium sized projects. Larger projects will have to
> tweak this value.

---

> Next to that, is there a way to allow for unlimited max heap and would that be a totally unreasonable thing to do?

At the time of writing, I am not aware of any JVM implementation allowing for unlimited memory and I honestly don't think it is advisable since it can slow down the system considerably.

Comment: Ouch, it's been before my very eyes all this time. Thank you very much.